# Global hotkey in PyKDE4 or PyQT4

Tags: pyqt4, pykde

How do set a global (system wide) keyboard shortcut, i.e. a shortcut that can be activated when any windows are in focus?

I'm implementing a window switcher and need to bind a keystroke to some some function.

I can see that KGlobalAccel might be useful, but a concrete example would be great. I'm not worried about blatting any current systemwide global hotkeys.